# using multiple criteria for grouping with the mongo 3 aggregation pipeline

Tags: java, mongodb

In the example found here (http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.2/builders/aggregation/), the aggregation grouping is based on `"$customerId"`:

```
collection.aggregate(Arrays.asList(match(eq("author", "Dave")),
             group("$customerId", sum("totalQuantity", "$quantity"),
                                  avg("averageQuantity", "$quantity"))
             out("authors")));
```

### **How would one add another grouping field into the aggregation pipepline, like say,** `"$systemId"`**?**

Within the **mongo-shell**, you would do something like this:

```
db.coll.aggregate(
  [
    {
      $group : {
        _id : {"customerId":"$customerId", "systemId":"$systemId"},
        //etc
      }
    }
  ]
)
```

In **Java**, you could build a query:

```
DBObject groupFields = new BasicDBObject();
DBObject groupIdFields = new BasicDBObject();
groupIdFields.put("customerId", "$customerID");
groupIdFields.put("systemId", "$systemId");
groupFields.put( "_id", groupIdFields );

//...
//... here some more aggregate criteria
//...

final AggregationOutput output = coll.aggregate(group);
```

Now, this seems like an awful lot of code just to get more than one grouping criterion. How is this possible with the aggregation pipeline in the **mongo 3 java driver**?